# Assignment statement not working

Tags: java, collections, shuffle

```
List<Integer> list = Collections.shuffle(list);
```

This assignment doesn't work. It gives "incompatible types" even though it's clearly a `List` and `.shuffle()` takes a `List`. So why won't this thing work?

Comment: `Collection`s are generally mutable. Operations on them generally occur in place.

Comment: Getting angry versus an API when you don't care reading the documentation is quite hilarious.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29). `Collections.shuffle` has a `void` return type. Create your `List` *first*, then shuffle. For example:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Collections.shuffle(list);
System.out.println("Shuffled List: " + list);
```

Comment: Note there is another issue, `List list = new ArrayList(list);` will not compile as well.

Comment: It modifys the `List` that you have passed in, so no need to assign, simply re-use the `list` reference.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two issues:

1. **You cannot access a variable before you initialize/declare it**, even the code `List list = new ArrayList(list);` will not work, because the right operand of the assignment is parsed before the left operand.
2. As mentioned by @Reimeus **`Collections.shuffle()` has a `void` return type**, thus you cannot assign it (the "result") to a variable. The method `shuffle()` changes the same list given as input (might be not intuitive for functional programmers).